# Is this an acceptable way to create a lock in Java ?

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency

I ran into this logic that someone had implemented at work today and it just feels wrong to be creating locks this way. Do you guys have a better solution for this ? The problem with not using synchronized block on myObj is that it can be null. Any other suggestions ??

```
 public class myClass {
    private Object myObj;
    private Object lock = new Object();

    public void method1() {
        synchronized( lock ) {
            // has logic to read myObj
        }
    }


    public void method2()  {
        synchronized( lock ) {
            // has logic to update myObj
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Look to the `java.util.concurrent` package.

Comment: make the lock `final`

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Looks appropriate to me. I'd also add `final` to the lock declaration to make sure it doesn't inadvertently get changed:

```
private final Object lock = new Object();
```

Comment: +1 for final, missed that tiny detail.

Answer (score 3):

It's appropriate. Another way, while it is hotly debated whether it is proper, is to synchronize `this` if you want to lock.

Answer (score 1):

I suppose you could `final` your `lock` field.  But your approach is fine in my opinion.

Answer (score 1):

I think it's acceptable.  Pre-Java 1.5 I don't think there was an alternative.  Nowadays you might prefer using one of the implementations of [`Lock`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/locks/Lock.html).

Answer (score 1):

The instance field `lock` should be marked final (so that we can be sure that the object referenced never changes). Other than that, it is appropriate. Consider using a [ReentrantReadWriteLock](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/locks/ReentrantReadWriteLock.html) instead which will give you the benefit of having a practically unlimited amount of concurrent readers. With `synchronized`, all threads but one will block independent of their type of operation.

If method1 and method2 are the only methods declared on myClass, then you could trade in your synchronized blocks and the lock variable for the keyword synchronized on the method declarations. Implicitly, the executing thread will try to get ownership of the monitor associated with the invoked instance of the class.

Here is a version of your class using a `ReentrantReadWriteLock` that will allow concurrent readers (also, write locks can "degrade" to read locks, not the other way around though):

```
import java.util.concurrent.locks.ReentrantReadWriteLock;

public class MyClass
{
    private Object myObject;

    private final ReentrantReadWriteLock myObjectLock = new ReentrantReadWriteLock();

    public void readMyObject()
    {
        ReentrantReadWriteLock.ReadLock r = myObjectLock.readLock();
        r.lock();

        try {
            ; // Read myObject.
        }

        finally {
            r.unlock();
        }
    }

    public void writeMyObject()
    {
        ReentrantReadWriteLock.WriteLock w = myObjectLock.writeLock();
        w.lock();

        try {
            ; // Write myObject.
        }

        finally {
            w.unlock();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this should not feel wrong creating such a lock! This is just the right way of making locks in java!

Answer (score 0):

You can use ReentrantLock. This is faster and more flexible compared to synchronized. See this [documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/locks/ReentrantLock.html) for more details.

Comment: What makes you say a ReentrantLock is faster? Since he uses Java synchronized mechanism under the cover, I think not. If by faster you mean that multiple readers are allowed, well then it depends on the situation. I did some research a while ago, and if I remember it correctly, it can not be shown that ReentrantLock is faster. Just a myth?

Comment: If anything is faster then it's the `synchronized` block because the JVM has an easier time optimizing it, for example through lock elision.

Comment: One can read about lock elision in Java over [here](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/java/library/j-jtp10185/).

Comment: I remember reading this article sometime back. [link]http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/java/library/j-jtp10264/

Comment: But BTW is Reentrant lock has synchronized below the hood ? I was hoping they are using CompareAndSwap

Answer (score 0):

Synchronizing on `this` (which is what you get by simply marking a method `synchronized`) makes your design vulnerable to deadlocks because the client of your class may acquire a lock on its instance and interfere with your own usage of the lock. That is the rationale behind using private instances as locks.

Whether this is a real concern in your particular codebase is another thing; it may just be overengineering. No "best practice" should be followed uncritically, without a clear pressure to do so.